# How do I configure compiler warnings in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, warnings

I recently started coding in C++ with Visual Studio 2010.

Now I am looking for an option to warn if a function has been declared, but not defined. That option would be found in the compiler options, wouldn't it? After a quick search on Google I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c553zwz0.aspx which is exactly what I needed... except (this may be due to me using the German version of Visual Studio) I can't find the compile tab on the Project properties.

Just to make sure: We have a solution (root node in the Solution explorer) and its child nodes are the projects (am I right?) after right clicking what translates to "properties" I end up in a window called "-Properties". But that window has no tab layout. It looks like this:

[image: Procjectname-Properties]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I doubt if any compiler would really provide flags to do that

Comment: And compile option in VS2010 (for C++) is under Build Menu. The help page you referred if for VS2010 for VB

Comment: To set compiler options, go to Project->Properties

Comment: Is the screenshot i showed you not of the properties window?

Comment: The MSDN link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that window expand '*Konfigurationseigenschaften*', expand the child '*C/C++*' and select '*Allgemein*'. Now you can set the warning level (Warnstufe) to **EnableAllWanings (/Wall)**.

Though I don't think the warning you are looking for exists, at least I couldn't produce it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzzzth4.aspx

Comment: I found your link as well, but it gives the same directives as mine posted above. So this does not solve my problem of finding the right window.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a function that is declared but not defined you will get an error at the linker stage.  It can't be done at the compiler stage because you would get tonnes of warnings as it only compiles one translation unit at a time.  Therefore anything including a header containing declarations would generate the warning despite the fact that ANOTHER translation unit DOES define it.  This is the whole point of the linker.  It goes through all these floating "declarations" and matches them up to the definition.